# CakePHP project migration to different server

Tags: cakephp, migration, web-hosting

I am trying to move a cakePHP project I completed a few months ago from a server (a friend's server) to my own web server.

I have set up a database and changed the database config file to match my database/login credentials.

when I navigate to http://babbage.cs.missouri.edu/~jam2z9/muve/index.php you see it looks as if it is a brand new project. When I go to just /muve instead of index.php it says I'm missing a ~jam2z9Controller file but I don't see any files from the old server that are like this to edit and change to ~jam2z9.

I feel like this should be a very simple transition once I hook up the database credentials but I'm just confused as to what my issue is?

All of the database tables in my new database are blank as I just imported the .sql file into phpMyAdmin. It all seems to be connecting fine but it will not go to the home page just the aforementioned generic cakephp screen?

Answer (score 0):

In your bootstrap.php add the following line:

```
Configure::write('App.base', '/~jam2z9/');
```

This is because as far as Cake sees it you are hosting it in a sub-sub directory.

Edit: There are more details about not being able to use mod_rewrite  [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#core-configuration)

Comment: Should I do this in my app/config/bootstrap.php file? I tried adding it in there but now i'm getting essentially the same error saying MuveController.php could not be found.

Comment: you might need to do /~jam2z9/muve/ - ideally you would have it set up so the document root is set to point to the /app/webroot directory

Comment: I feel like it's getting closer to working! Now when I visit http://babbage.cs.missouri.edu/~jam2z9/muve/ it's a simple url rewriting error but the server does not allow that. I remove all .htaccess files and uncomment the line in my core.php file but it still has the error and I'm back to being stuck :( 

I did delete the default.ctp file when it was on the other server, could that be an issue? I still have the file on git but didn't think that would matter once the project was complete.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another link if you cant use mod_rewrite, update your question with the errors you are getting now, its possible if you deleted default.ctp you could be getting a different error.